# Jupyter Notebooks not running on VS Code Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have installed latest Python 3 `(python-3.11.0-amd64)` and latest VS Code `(VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.73.1)`. I also installed  the "Python Extension for Visual Studio Code".

[image]

which as you can see it claimed that it comes with Jupyter Notebooks feature to Create and edit `Jupyter Notebooks`

I have selected the interpreter:

[image]

and selected the **Kernel**:

[image]

which is listed as:

[image]

but when I ran the cell, I am getting this error message, asking for **Jupyter Package**:

[image]

> Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate Jupyter: Running
> cells with 'Python 3.11.0 64-bit' requires notebook and jupyter
> package. Run the following command to install 'jupyter and notebook'
> into the Python environment.  Command: 'python -m pip install jupyter
> notebook -U or conda install jupyter notebook -U' Click here for more
> info.

As you can see "Juputer" has been installed but

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: The Python environment you use needs to include [the Jupyter package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/). The error message says, "Run the following command to install 'jupyter and notebook' into the Python environment. Command: 'python -m pip install jupyter notebook -U'". Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I updated the post with error message but you didnt answer my question. I asked while the `Jupyter Notebook` is installed by ` Python Extension for Visual Studio Code` I need to intall the package again

Comment: You installed a Jupyter-related extension to your text editor.  That doesn't change the Python installation it uses.

Comment: The error message isn't about the Visual Studio Code plugin, it's about Python package that the plugin (like all other Jupyter interfaces) uses.

Comment: So I still need to install the `Jupyter Package`  among  `Python Extension for Visual Studio Code`! Got it! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you must download the full package of Anaconda** and **install it** into your system.

Here are the All Anaconda download links :

[Installing on Windows](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)

[Installing on macOS](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)

[Installing on Linux](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/)

[Installing on AWS Graviton2 (arm64)](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/graviton2/)

[Installing on Linux-s390x (IBM Z)](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux-s390x/)

[Installing on Linux POWER](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux-power8/)

[Installing in silent mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/)

[Installing for multiple users](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/)

Answer (score 0):

The error prompt actually tells you how to solve the problem. Click install can solve it.

The Jupyter Notebook is an extension which needs jupyter package. So you have to install jupyter package by using command

`pip install jupyter notebook`.

The use steps in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter#quick-start) also specify: Install Anaconda/Miniconda or another Python environment in **which you've installed the Jupyter package**